# Cognos 10 fixed MM/dd but variable year

Tags: cognos-10

Want to set July 01 as month and day but have a variable for the year.  Always want to default to year of most recent past July 01.

Has to work within the parameters present in Cognos 10.2.  Tried several If statements with date2strings and string2date functions.  Also tried a series of columns designed to filter data recursively.

logic 
If current_month <= 6 then year(current_date, -1 ) else year(current_date). Want to concatenate the year with xxxx-06-01 or preferably 06/01/xxxx.  Keep getting run-time errors, not errors in Query Calculation.

Can't see the forest for the trees at this point. Continue to explore, will post solution if achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to keep dates in date format and avoid conversion to string and concatenation if possible. Cognos gives you several native functions to manipulate dates without having to convert.

Here's your expression:

```
_add_years(
    _add_months(
        _first_of_month(
            current_date
        ),
        7 - extract(
            month,
            current_date
        )
    ),
    floor(
        extract(
            month,
            current_date
        )
        / 7
    ) - 1
)
```

It easier to understand if you examine it inside out.

The _first_of_month() function returns the first day of the current month. We then use some math to determine an offset to pass into the _add_months() function that will turn the first of the current month into the first of July in the current year for every possible month value. Lastly, we use math again to either add 0 or 1 years to the resulting date using the _add_years() function. For all months less than 7, we add -1 and for months 7 and greater we add 0.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Will explore your expression at more length.  I posted a solution that works above.  Please feel free to critique my solution.

Answer (score 0):

This works.  Still trying to figure out how _make_timestamp () magically knows the Current FY start date?

if ( month( current_date ) < 7 ) then ( _make_timestamp ( [Year of Today] - 1, 7, 1 ) ) else 
if ( month( current_date ) > 6 ) then ( _make_timestamp ( [Year of Today] + 0, 7, 1 ) ) else NULL

Comment: Your solution should work as well. I don't see any "magic" here. You are telling it what your fiscal year start date is implicitly in your IF condition. If the month is 6 and below, we are in one fiscal year and if it's 7 and above we are in the next fiscal year.

Comment: Yes, the solution does work.  Have run it through several iterations.  Appreciate your time.